# How disable ENTER keyboard interaction in datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, datapicker

Here:
http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/
I see:

> Keyboard interaction
>
> While the datepicker is open, the following key commands are
>   available:
>
> ```
> PAGE UP: Move to the previous month.
> PAGE DOWN: Move to the next month.
> CTRL + PAGE UP: Move to the previous year.
> CTRL + PAGE DOWN: Move to the next year.
> CTRL + HOME: Open the datepicker if closed.
> CTRL/COMMAND + HOME: Move to the current month.
> CTRL/COMMAND + LEFT: Move to the previous day.
> CTRL/COMMAND + RIGHT: Move to the next day.
> CTRL/COMMAND + UP: Move to the previous week.
> CTRL/COMMAND + DOWN: Move the next week.
> ENTER: Select the focused date.
> CTRL/COMMAND + END: Close the datepicker and erase the date.
> ESCAPE: Close the datepicker without selection.
> ```

I don't want:

> ENTER: Select the focused date.

interaction

Is it possible to disable a single interaction? My Enter key in a particular field must not set the date on my field. My Enter key must do something else in that field (and it does), just don't want even to set the date in the field.

Comment: try adding 
`$('.className').on('keypress', function(e)
{
   if(e.keyCode == 13)
   {
      return false;
   }
});`

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myDate").datepicker().on("keydown", function(e){
        if (e.which == 13) {
            $("#myDate").val('');
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```